# "there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "Profiles"" while creating many to many association

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I am trying to use typescript and sequelize to create a many to many relationship between the Profile model and Housing model. A profile has many housings associated with it. A given housing entry may have many profiles associated with it. I figure I'm pretty close, but it's the first time I've made one of these. Hence I get the error

```
Database connection failed Error
    at Query.run (/home/rlm/Code/apGymBE/node_modules/sequelize/src/dialects/postgres/query.js:76:25)
    at /home/rlm/Code/apGymBE/node_modules/sequelize/src/sequelize.js:641:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async PostgresQueryInterface.addColumn (/home/rlm/Code/apGymBE/node_modules/sequelize/src/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js:430:12)
    at async Function.sync (/home/rlm/Code/apGymBE/node_modules/sequelize/src/model.js:1373:11)
    at async Sequelize._syncModelsWithCyclicReferences (/home/rlm/Code/apGymBE/node_modules/sequelize/src/sequelize.js:847:7) {
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  parent: error: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "Profiles"
      at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/home/rlm/Code/apGymBE/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:369:69)
      at Parser.handlePacket (/home/rlm/Code/apGymBE/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:188:21)
      at Parser.parse (/home/rlm/Code/apGymBE/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:103:30)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/rlm/Code/apGymBE/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/index.ts:7:48)

// later in the error
 sql: 'ALTER TABLE "public"."Profile_Housings" ADD COLUMN "ProfileProfileId" INTEGER  REFERENCES "Profiles" ("profileId") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;',
    parameters: undefined
  },
  original: error: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "Profiles"
```

This error message must be something during model and intermediary table creation. Because it says **Profile_Housings** which I mention later in my associations.

Here is my Profile model:

```
interface ProfileAttributes {
    profileId?: number;
    accountId?: number;
    ipAddress: string;
    pickedHousingIds?: number[];
    pickedGymIds?: number[];
    createdAt?: Date;
    updatedAt?: Date;
    deletedAt?: Date;
}

export type ProfileOptionalAttributes = "createdAt" | "updatedAt" | "deletedAt";
export type ProfileCreationAttributes = Optional<ProfileAttributes, ProfileOptionalAttributes>;

export class Profile extends Model<ProfileAttributes, ProfileCreationAttributes> implements ProfileAttributes {
    public profileId!: number;
    public accountId!: ForeignKey<Account["acctId"]>;
    public ipAddress!: string;

    public readonly createdAt!: Date;
    public readonly updatedAt!: Date;
    public readonly deletedAt!: Date;

    declare getHousings: HasManyGetAssociationsMixin<Housing>;
    declare addHousing: HasManyAddAssociationMixin<Housing, number>;
    declare addHousings: HasManyAddAssociationsMixin<Housing, number>;

    public readonly Housings?: Housing[];

    public static associations: {
        Housings: Association<Profile, Housing>;
    };

    static initModel(sequelize: S): typeof Profile {
        return Profile.init(
            {
                profileId: {
                    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                    unique: true,
                    autoIncrement: true,
                    primaryKey: true,
                },
                ipAddress: {
                    type: DataTypes.STRING,
                    allowNull: false,
                },
            },
            {
                timestamps: true,
                sequelize: sequelize,
                paranoid: false,
            },
        );
    }
}
```

Here is my Housing model:

```
interface HousingAttributes {
    housingId?: number;
    address: string;
    taskId?: number;
    cityId?: number;
    stateId?: number;
    batchId?: number;
    createdAt?: Date;
    updatedAt?: Date;
    deletedAt?: Date;
}

export type HousingOptionalAttributes = "createdAt" | "updatedAt" | "deletedAt" | "cityId";
export type HousingCreationAttributes = Optional<HousingAttributes, HousingOptionalAttributes>;

export class Housing extends Model<HousingAttributes, HousingCreationAttributes> implements HousingAttributes {
    public housingId!: number;
    public address!: string;
    public taskId!: ForeignKey<Task["taskId"]>;
    public cityId!: ForeignKey<City["cityId"]>;
    public stateId!: ForeignKey<State["stateId"]>;
    public batchId!: ForeignKey<Batch["batchId"]>;

    public readonly createdAt!: Date;
    public readonly updatedAt!: Date;
    public readonly deletedAt!: Date;

    public readonly Profiles?: Profile[];

    public static associations: {
        Profiles: Association<Housing, Profile>;
    };

    static initModel(sequelize: Sequelize): typeof Housing {
        return Housing.init(
            {
                housingId: {
                    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                    autoIncrement: true,
                    primaryKey: true,
                },
                address: {
                    type: DataTypes.STRING,
                    allowNull: false,
                },
            },
            {
                timestamps: true,
                sequelize: sequelize,
            },
        );
    }
}
```

and I initialize the relationship like

```
    // https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/advanced-many-to-many/
    Profile.belongsToMany(Housing, { through: "Profile_Housings", as: "chosen_housings" });
    Housing.belongsToMany(Profile, { through: "Profile_Housings", as: "housings_chosen_by" });
```

[The docs for Advanced M:N Associations](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/advanced-many-to-many/) indicate I've done everything correctly so far *unless im misreading it, which is possible*. [The typescript version](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/typescript/) looks pretty close too though they don't mention many-to-many associations at all. What am I missing?

edit: hypothesis right now is that everything was fine except that my db had to be dropped and remade

Answer (score 0):

As of an hour ago the issue disappeared, and my only action I noticed making a difference was deleting and remaking the db in postgres.